# Get 3 most visiting customers from table T1 and get top 5 products each one of them buy from table T2

Tags: sql, db2

I need to fetch 3 most visiting customers from table T1 and get and top 5 products EACH ONE OF THEM buy from table T2.

TABLE T1 has 
    KIRK visited 3 times, Hulk 3 times, John 2 times .. so these three should be fetched only. Thor and Rndm guy visited once so they r left as only top three were to be fetched

```
Table 1 (T1)
-----------------------------------
NAME       AGE   VISITOR CODE
-----------------------------------
KIRK     18    1285
THOR     99    1284
KIRK     18    1285
HULK     19    1286
KIRK     18    1285
JOHN     19    0007   
HULK     19    1286
JOHN     19    0007
HULK     19    1286
RNDM     19    0008


 Table 2 (T2)
-----------------------------------
PRODUCT  MRP   VISITOR CODE    --EXAMPLE ONLY FOR KIRK TOP 3 PRODS ARE A then D then C.
-----------------------------------
A        111    1285
A        111    1285
A        111    1285
B        191    1285
C        192    1285
C        192    1285
D        190    1285
D        190    1285
D        190    1285
D        190    1285
```

WHAT I TRIED IS :

```
SELECT                              
       T2.PRODUCT ,                  
       COUNT(*) AS X                  
  FROM T1,T2
 WHERE T2.VISITOR CODE =
      (SELECT                              
              T1.VISITOR CODE ,                  
              COUNT(*) AS X                  
       FROM  T1,T2
       GROUP BY T1.VISITOR CODE 
       ORDER BY X DESC        
       FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY)
 GROUP BY T1.VISITOR CODE 
 ORDER BY X DESC
```

THE PROBLEM IS: I only need T1.VISITOR CODE from sub query as to match with T2 table's T2.VISITOR CODE.
But i have also used count in T1 table sub query.

OUTPUT RESULT:

```
NAME     PRODUCT     VISITOR CODE 
KIRK     A           1285
KIRK     D           1285
KIRK     C           1285
HULK     C           1286
HULK     A           1286
HULK     B           1286 -- AND THEN  JOHN AND HIS 3 PRODUCTS
```

Comment: `FROM  T1,T2` T1 and t2 are not joined in any way, so you will get a carthesian product.

Comment: @wildplasser I believe visitor code is the key between them

Answer (score 1):

You can use derived tables to solve this query. The first derived table contains the top 3 visitors, which is joined to the 2nd derived table that contains the top 5 products for each visitor.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM
    (SELECT
        NAME,
        AGE,
        VISITOR_CODE,
        COUNT(*) VISIT_COUNT
    FROM
        TABLE1t t1
    GROUP BY VISITOR_CODE
    ORDER BY VISIT_COUNT DESC LIMIT 3) t1
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        PRODUCT,
        MRP,
        VISITOR_CODE,
        RANK() OVER 
        (PARTITION BY t3.VISITOR_CODE ORDER BY t3.product_count DESC) AS rank
    FROM (
        SELECT
            PRODUCT,
            MRP,
            VISITOR_CODE,
            COUNT(*) product_count
        FROM TABLE2
        GROUP BY
            PRODUCT,
            MRP,
            VISITOR_CODE
    ) t3 WHERE rank <= 5
) t2 ON t1.VISITOR_CODE = t2.VISITOR_CODE
```

Comment: you have said previousVisitorCode. But, previousVisitorCode is not kept anywhere ?

Comment: @AgentMahone, for some reason I thought you're using mysql. Updated the query for db2, though I'm not sure if it's correct. Give it a try :)

Comment: I dont get it how we are getting top 5 products for every visitor.
like Kirk was top visitor.. 
so output should show KIRK with top 5 products he bought
    KIRK  PROD A
    KIRK  PROD B .. etc then Hulk will come in with his 5 products
then the thrid visitor with his 5 most purchased products

Comment: @AgentMahone Product counts for all visitor/product/mrp combinations are retrieved from derived table `t3`. Those results are ranked with `RANK() OVER ...` and only the top 5 are kept for each visitor.